# Best way to 'animate' images in an Image control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a program that displays all kinds of weather data and imagery from the Met Office and I want to add a live animation function for the imagery datasets.

Currently, the imagery dataset pages have a ListView that contains items with the original time, the time formatted for display and the path to its PNG image layer file. There is also an Image control that displays the image by setting its source to the path of the currently selected ListView item.

At the moment I am using a dispatcher timer to increment the selected index of the ListView which will in turn fire its SelectionChanged event to set the image source to the currently selected item. But the DispatcherTimer is laggy so much that it looks like its interval fluctuates past other user selectable intervals. This is the current code:

```
times.SelectedIndex = times.SelectedIndex == 0 ? times.Items.Count - 1 : times.SelectedIndex - 1;
```

And for the SelectionChanged event of the ListView:

```
if (times.SelectedItem != null)
{
    try
    {
         data.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(((Time)times.SelectedItem).Directory));
         dataOriginal.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(((Time)times.SelectedItem).Directory.Replace("_LORES.png", "_HIRES.png")));
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

I need a better way to loop through the items to get a live animation and it needs to be able to support intervals of around only a few milliseconds to a few seconds to get slow and very fast animations without lagging. I basically want something exactly like what you see on most weather maps online where it animates through the time but that can have much faster speeds. Also, I am using WPF. I hope I have not explained this too much, thanks.

Comment: Is that image control you are talking about present per row or next to the ListView? Could you explain us why would you want to run through all items and select each of them? Shouldn't user pick a line?

Comment: @devhedgehog There is a single Image next to a ListView and the user selects an item from the ListView and it changes the source of the Image to the file path of the selected item. There is an animation mode which can be turned on and it automatically selects each item one after another

Comment: Ok, I see the picture clearer. Still not completely. Could you post more code please its still hard to see exactly where you wish to tune you performance. Could you upload yor project? Changing source of Image control isnt that much of a big deal. I would love to see the code. I think then I would be able to provide you with exact solution. How many items are there in your ListView? If you cannot post us code I would suggest you to mark your Bindings as Async. Like this: Source = "{Binding someSrc, Mode=OneWay, Async=True}". Try it out.